# R Shiny and use of port 3838: a security vulnerability?

Tags: r, security, web-applications, shiny

I'm going to deploy an R Shiny server (on Redhat) and it seems as if port 3838, which Shiny uses, may pose a security threat. I have sensitive raw data, which must not be accessed by the end user, who should, though, be able to access the Shiny app without logging in. So the Shiny app is an open applications, and I want to make sure noone exploits potential vulnerability of using port 3838.

Questions:

- Is port 3838 a security vulnerability?
- Alternatives that are safe and secure?

Very grateful for any advice.

Comment: Not much of an expert in the field, but I can't see how a specific port might be a vulnerability by itself. I guess you are as safe as deploying through port 7547 for instance.

Comment: The port is not the security issue itself. If you have sensitive data but anybody can access then the data is simply not safe in any sense. I think it makes no sense to secure the connection when you have no login. The shiny server Pro version offers both but is much to expansive for most of the applications I know. Some issues are discussed here [link](https://ipub.com/shiny-https/) and here [link](https://www.shinyproxy.io/)